# Dynamically locking cells in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have four columns (A,B,C,D). My requirement is that in each row, only one cell should accept data, and the remaining cells should not accept data (i.e. the remaining three cells should be in locked mode).

How do I do this?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Are you trying to lock 3 columns so that users can't input anything in those columns?

Comment: As I understand this, you are looking to allow only 1 of 4 cells in a group to be modified. i.e. If Col C has a value, leave A, B, D empty. Correct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's one way to do what you ask. (Or at least what I think you're asking.)

First, unlock all the cells in the sheet. By default they are all in locked state (though this does not take effect until you actually protect the sheet) so you need to unlock them to start with, otherwise you won't be able to input any data anywhere as soon as you protect the sheet. You can do this manually (In 2003: Select all cells, Format > Cells > Protection > uncheck "Locked") or using VBA as follows:

```
Sub UnlockAll()
    With Sheet1 ' Or whatever sheet you're working on
        .Unprotect
        .Cells.Locked = False
        .Protect
    End With
End Sub
```

The above only needs to be executed once.

Then you have to use the `Worksheet_Change` event to lock and unlock cells dynamically. In your sheet's module, write this code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Me.Unprotect
    If Not IsEmpty(Target) Then
        'Data was added in target cell. Lock its neighbours.
        Me.Cells(Target.Row, 1).Resize(, 4).Locked = True
        Target.Locked = False
    Else
        'Data was erased from target cell. Release its neighbours.
        Me.Cells(Target.Row, 1).Resize(, 4).Locked = False
    End If
    Me.Protect
End Sub
```

Say you write data in cell B2; this will lock cells B1, B3, and B4 so that no data can be entered. If you later decide to clear cell B2, then this will unlock B1, B3, and B4.

Comment: Thanq  Jean-François Corbett,

Comment: good answer,  but i want same kind of behavior for other columns also i.e now  (A-D) columns has that behavior ok , simillary  I need same behaviour for  (M-Q) Columns  in same Excel sheet

Comment: Look, I answered the question. If you have a new question, then accept this answer and post a new question. Perhaps before posting a new question, you can try to understand this solution, and adapt it to work for columns M-Q as well as A-D.

Comment: This solution is not working. when there is data in fifth or sixth or so on ....columns the starting four columns are getting locked.

Comment: Thanq Jean  its working very fine. but my quesition if the cell is locked even i try to enter something in that cell, it is showing a predefined alert, How to i use my own alert Message instead of that.      Advanced Thanqs Jean You Helped a lot