# How to make Dynamic locking and unlocking for four colums in Excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I considered only Four columns in Excel sheet (i.e A,B,C,D) all remaining columns should have default in nature.

My doubt is if i select any cell in Each row of that four columns, than remaining cells should not accept any data i.e those should go to locked mode, like this i want to do from top to bottom of Excel page (i.e. this effect for only four columns remaining column should have default behaviour)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamically locking cells in Excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9686789/dynamically-locking-cells-in-excel)

Comment: Above JF's comments, I see that you are quite new here. In Stackoverflow, if an answer fits you, please accept it by clicking on the tick on the left of the answer - see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234 for more information. You can go back to the previous question you asked to accept Jean-François' answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean, but you could try the following:

```
Sub ApplyLock      
  Dim sh as WorkSheet
  set sh = ActiveSheet
  sh.Range(sh.range("E1"),sh.cells(sh.rows.count,sh.cells.count)).Locked = True
  sh.protect userinterfaceonly:=true      
End Sub
```

Edit: After re-reading, it looks like you might want only the first four columns protected. In that case:

```
Sub ApplyLock      
  Dim sh as WorkSheet
  set sh = ActiveSheet
  sh.Range("A:D").Locked = True
  sh.protect userinterfaceonly:=true
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I have already [answered your very similar earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9690400/119775).

The only difference in this case is that you want "default behaviour" in all other columns than A to D. What do you mean by "default behaviour"? You don't mention this in your question.

If you mean that the user should be able to input data in them and modify them as usual, with cells *not* locked for editing, then [my answer to your earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9690400/119775) does do exactly that.

If you mean that all columns after D *should* be locked for editing, then the only thing you need to do is replace

```
        .Cells.Locked = False
```

with

```
        .Range("A:D").Locked = False
```

This will unlock only columns A to D, leaving all others locked.